# Python Pymongo is not updating an existing document

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I am trying to update an existing document in MongoDB with the code below:

```
def insert_data(conn, documents):
    for document in documents:
        new_document = document.split(',')
        result = conn.update_one({ '_id': new_document[0] },
                        { '$set': { "type": new_document[1] } }, upsert=True)
        print(result.raw_result)
    return print('Done')
```

My print returning:

```
{'n': 1, 'nModified': 0, 'ok': 1.0, 'updatedExisting': True}
{'n': 1, 'nModified': 0, 'ok': 1.0, 'updatedExisting': True}
{'n': 1, 'nModified': 0, 'ok': 1.0, 'updatedExisting': True}
{'n': 1, 'nModified': 0, 'ok': 1.0, 'updatedExisting': True}
{'n': 1, 'nModified': 0, 'ok': 1.0, 'updatedExisting': True}
```

But my data on MongoDB still without this property.

Additional info: "TYPE" attribute doesn't exists, this update should create this attribute and set new value.

Am I doing something wrong or should I use other function to do that?

Python 3.7

Pymongo 3.9.0

Thanks!!

Document:

```
{
    "_id" : 4,
    "name" : "Cultura",
    "broadcast" : "teste",
    "frequency" : "102.5",
    "modulation" : "FM",
    "protocol" : 8,
    "campaign" : 0,
    "status" : 0,
    "cmixCast" : null,
    "city" : {
        "id" : 2969,
        "name" : "Maringá"
    },
    "state" : {
        "id" : 16,
        "name" : "Paraná",
        "uf" : "PR"
    },
    "nodeId" : null,
    "__v" : 0,
    "utc" : -3,
    "ffmpeg" : 1,
    "newStation" : 0,
    "deletedAt" : "2019-09-27 17:31:41",
    "square" : 0,
    "musicalAction" : 0,
    "url" : "http://www.cultura.fm.br/",
    "observations" : null,
    "region" : {
        "id" : 5,
        "name" : "Sul"
    },
    "contacts" : [],
    "recorder" : {
        "queue" : 0.0,
        "status" : 0.0
    }
}
```

Comment: What is in `new_document[0]`? Does it have the same data type as `_id`? Usually `_id ` is of type `ObjectId`. If `new_document[0]` is a string it could be that you need to replace `new_document[0]` with `bson.ObejctId(new_document[0])`. The `bson ` package is installed with `pymongo`. You should be able to import it

Comment: I updated the question with the document

Comment: I found the problem, as you said, I just putted `int(document[0])` and `str(document[1])`, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def insert_data(conn, documents):
    for document in documents:
        new_document = document.split(', ')
        result = conn.update_one({ '_id': int(new_document[0]) },
                        { '$set': { "type": str(new_document[1]) } })
        print(result.raw_result)
    return print('Done')
```

just added cast int() and str() before variables, and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to insert a document as the first parameter into the `update_one` method.

```
def insert_data(conn, documents):
    for document in documents:
        new_document = document.split(',')
        result = conn.update_one(document,
                        { '$set': { "type": str(new_document[1]) } })
        print(result.raw_result)
    return print('Done')
```